# Uploading image to mysql database through android

Tags: java, php, android

Hello before someone says that i shouldnt store in database as blob, well i need it i have my reasons. Last time i asked this only response i got was like dont store in database or something. Well here is my code thatone part works the other part doesnt works, the part that works is taking photo and displaying it in imageview , not working is uploading to mysql database. If more information is needed tell me i will edit answer. thank you in advance.

Code

Activity:

```
public class takefoto extends BaseNavegationActivity {

Button takebt, sendbt;
String ba1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
ImageView mFoto;
int CodServico;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.takefoto);

    takebt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takebt);
    mFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fotoser);
    takebt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    sendbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbt);
    sendbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            upload();
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    CodServico=extras.getInt("CodServico");
    Log.i("CODSERVICO",CodServico+"");

}

private void upload() {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);

    // Upload image to server
    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(takefoto.this);
    serverRequests.storeFotoDataInBackground(ba1, CodServico, new GetUpdaterCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(String returnUser) {
            if (returnUser.equalsIgnoreCase("sucesso")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enviado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                showError();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void captureImage() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        setPic();
    }
}

private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mFoto.getWidth();
    int targetH = mFoto.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}

private void showError(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente mais tarde.");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
}
```

ServerResquest method:

```
public  void storeFotoDataInBackground(String ba, int codservico,GetUpdaterCallBack userCallback){
    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreFotoDataAsyncTasck(ba, codservico, userCallback).execute();
}
public class StoreFotoDataAsyncTasck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String ba;
    int CodServico;
    GetUpdaterCallBack registerCallback;

    public StoreFotoDataAsyncTasck(String ba1, int codservico,GetUpdaterCallBack registerCallback) {
        this.ba = ba1;
        this.CodServico=codservico;
        this.registerCallback = registerCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String retorno = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "myphpfile.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("CodServico", this.CodServico+"")
                    .appendQueryParameter("Imagem", this.ba);
            Log.i("IMAGEM",this.ba+" CodServico"+this.CodServico);
            final String postParameters = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParameters.getBytes().length);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //send the POST out
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            pw.print(postParameters);
            pw.close();
            conn.connect();
            String result = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if(jObject.length()!=0){
                retorno= jObject.getString("estado");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$codservic=$_POST['CodServico'];        
$image = $_POST['Imagem'];          
$con = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx") or die('Unable To connect');
$sql = "insert into xxxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxx) values(?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is",$codservic,$image);
$sucesso=mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if($sucesso){
    $estado = array();
    $estado[estado] = "sucesso";
    echo json_encode($estado);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after lot's of search i got it finnaly to work for those who need it too i will post my code.

Main activity:

```
public class takefoto extends BaseNavegationActivity {

Button takebt, sendbt;
String ba1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;
ImageView mFoto;
int CodServico;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.takefoto);

    takebt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takebt);
    mFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fotoser);
    takebt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            captureImage();
        }
    });

    sendbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbt);
    sendbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            upload();
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    CodServico=extras.getInt("CodServico");
    Log.i("CODSERVICO",CodServico+"");

}

private void upload() {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    Log.i("IMAGEM NAO CONVERTIDA",ba+"");
    ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);
    // Get image and
    // Upload image to server
    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(takefoto.this);
    serverRequests.storeFotoDataInBackground(ba1, CodServico, new GetUpdaterCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(String returnUser) {
            if (returnUser.equalsIgnoreCase("sucesso")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enviado!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                showError();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void captureImage() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 100);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        setPic();
    }
}

private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mFoto.getWidth();
    int targetH = mFoto.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Getpath", "Cool" + mCurrentPhotoPath);
    return image;
}

private void showError(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente mais tarde.");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
}
```

Server requests method(the part of the insert with database):

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String retorno = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(SERVER_ADDRESS + "yourphpfile.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("Value1", this.CodServico+"")
                    .appendQueryParameter("Image", this.ba);
            Log.i("IMAGEM",""+this.ba);
            final String postParameters = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParameters.getBytes().length);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //send the POST out
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            pw.print(postParameters);
            pw.close();
            conn.connect();
            String result = convertStreamToString(conn.getInputStream());
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            if(jObject.length()!=0){
                retorno= jObject.getString("status");// if was sucess or not
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$codservic=$_POST['Value1'];    
$image = $_POST['Image'];
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
$img = base64_decode($image);
$con = mysqli_connect("your connection string") or die('Unable To connect');
$sql = "insert into yourtable (yourcamp1,image) values(?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"is",$codservic,$img);
$sucesso=mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$estado = array();
if($sucesso){
    $estado[status] = "sucess";
    echo json_encode($estado);
} else {
    $estado[status] = "error";
    echo json_encode($estado);
}
?>
```